# Sound is lost when concatenate several videos with ffmpeg

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I have a python script that generates an FFmpeg command and then runs it with shell.
Everything is going okay (the videos are concatenated, the needed cross-dissolve effect is also great), but there are two problems I am trying to fix:

1. The output loses the sound.
2. The output is frizzing a little bit (it seems like there are about 10 fps).

The example of command generatede by the script is here:

```
ffmpeg -i /tmp/media/import-2020-Aug-18-Tuesday-08-31-10/temp_8ce3c8ac-
1379-4a16-b141-ebdc910e1142.mp4 -i /tmp/media/import-2020-Aug-18-
Tuesday-08-31-10/temp_d9f60ffb-0a83-4052-8ebb-620a574d1871.mp4 -i 
/tmp/media/import-2020-Aug-18-Tuesday-08-31-10/temp_93934eaa-9589-4736-
8d11-fd8c1bdf0b92.mp4  -filter_complex "
[0:v]trim=start=0:end=4.038,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[clip0];
[1:v]trim=start=2:end=4.038,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[clip1];
[2:v]trim=start=2,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[clip2];
[0:v]trim=start=5.038:end=6.038,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[out0];
[1:v]trim=start=5.038:end=6.038,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[out1];
[1:v]trim=start=0:end=2,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[in1];
[2:v]trim=start=0:end=2,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[in2];
[in1]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=2:alpha=1[fadein1];
[in2]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=2:alpha=1[fadein2];
[out0]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=out:st=0:d=2:alpha=1[fadeout0];
[out1]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=out:st=0:d=2:alpha=1[fadeout1];
[fadein1]fifo[fadein1fifo];[fadein2]fifo[fadein2fifo];
[fadeout0]fifo[fadeout0fifo];[fadeout1]fifo[fadeout1fifo];[fadeout0fifo]
[fadein1fifo]overlay[crossfade0];[fadeout1fifo]
[fadein2fifo]overlay[crossfade1];[clip0][crossfade0][clip1][crossfade1]
[clip2]concat=n=5[output]" -map "[output]" 
/tmp/media/final/some_filename_c8e898b2-e3f7-4656-b3b9-1e8fb93cd75c.mp4
```

I would much appreciate any help because I am new to this tool and here I got stuck.

Comment: I believe you are only using the video streams (`[0:v]`, `[1:v]` and `[2:v]`). Shouldn't you do something similar for the audio streams (probably `[0:a]`, `[1:a]` and `[2:a]`)?

Comment: @HernánAlarcón after a few hours of trying to understand the ffmpeg syntax I came to this solution. Can you suggest what the syntax of including the audio to the filter_complex should be?

Comment: Actually, I found a way to do it - I concatenated the audio from videos and then merge the resulting video with the resulting audio.